put a texture on single face of glb model load
my goal is to load a texture onto a 3D object, but only on one face. When I load the texture as a material, it loads onto the entire object, and when I assign a material array with just the texture where it's needed, it doesn't load any material. i use threejs + nextjs
constructor(
    geo: THREE.BufferGeometry<THREE.NormalBufferAttributes>,
    p: directionNull,
    id: number,
    poss: coordonee,
    mat?: THREE.MeshBasicMaterial[]
  ) {
    super(
      geo,

      [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0) }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0) }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0) }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0) }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("txt.png"),
        }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0) }),
      ]
      // new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff })
    );
    console.log(this.geometry);

    this.position.setX(poss.x);
    this.position.setY(poss.y);
    this.oldPossition = { x: this.position.x, y: this.position.y };
    this.index = id;
    this.addHitBox(p);
    this.idMove = crypto.randomUUID();
  }

don t work
constructor(
    geo: THREE.BufferGeometry<THREE.NormalBufferAttributes>,
    p: directionNull,
    id: number,
    poss: coordonee,
    mat?: THREE.MeshBasicMaterial[]
  ) {
    super(
      geo,

      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("txt.png"),
      })

      // new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff })
    );
    console.log(this.geometry);

    this.position.setX(poss.x);
    this.position.setY(poss.y);
    this.oldPossition = { x: this.position.x, y: this.position.y };
    this.index = id;
    this.addHitBox(p);
    this.idMove = crypto.randomUUID();
  }

work but load the texture on all object ...
Any hint is welcome, and thank you for your responses/reading.
i need the texture on only one face of my object
